# Regex For Match a Hierarchical URL

Tags: asp.net, regex, url, web

I have this Regex

```
^([^\.]+)\.aspx$
```

which matches only the following

```
FolPage.aspx
~/FolPage.aspx
~/Folder/FolPage.aspx
~/Folder/Folder1/Folder2/FolPage.aspx
~/Folder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/FolPage.aspx
```

I want a regex which matches above url and also below Url's

```
../FolPage.aspx
../Folder/FolPage.aspx
../Folder/Folder1/Folder2/FolPage.aspx
../Folder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/FolPage.aspx
```

You can see the demo **[Here..!!](http://rubular.com/r/dDYCojndYi)**

Actually I'm trying to do URL Rewriting..

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([^\.]+)\.aspx$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" negate="true" pattern="^POST$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:1}}/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([^/]+)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

i need regex for both **Redirect** and **Rewrite**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this regex:

```
^( *\.\.)?([^\.]+)\.aspx$
```

[rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/Fjya4dNlTx)

`( *\.\.)?` matches optional spaces followed by double dots.

Comment: It's working man... but this is my rewrite url regex `^([^/]+)/$`. in this case it's not working

Comment: @VigneshKumar Hmm, could you clarify? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Actually Im trying to do URL Rewriting

Comment: @VigneshKumar Okay, I think this is a it different from matching the above urls right? While I know it's a follow up question, it might be more suitable as a different question. That's still okay if you don't want to write another, but I will need more clarification. For instance, to what url are you trying to rewrite? What code are you using?

Comment: I have updated my question . can you please take a look at my question

Comment: @VigneshKumar Okay, I admit these conditions look a bit complex for me. Um, would using the same regex for both the redirect and the rewrite work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that works:

`/^([~\.]{1,2})([^\.]+)\.aspx$/`

http://rubular.com/r/WqLtHxolkf

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
^(?:\.\.|[^\.])+\.aspx$
```

It means either `..` or `not .`

Comment: @VigneshKumar I removed group capturing using `?:` in my regex. if you want you have to remove that from regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^(\.{2}|~)?.+\.aspx$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

```
http://rubular.com/r/UPoFog0Abj
```